# STM32 with display not showing whole screen

Tags: stm32

I have a STM32F4 custom built PCB with a 0.96 inch TFT 80x160 display (https://www.buydisplay.com/0-96-inch-mini-color-tft-lcd-display-module-80x160-ips-tft-st7735) using ST7735 Driver (https://controllerstech.com/st7735-1-8-tft-display-with-stm32/)

I get the screen to work and it can do the "testAll()" function which basically does a lot of things on the screen to see that it is working. But the problem is that not the whole display is on.
[image: Display with top not showing][image: Display with top not showing]

Now from the pictures it could seem like there are some dead pixels on top and that the display is broken. But this is not the case since I can do a rotation (this is function declaration void ST7735_Init(uint8_t rotation))
Rotation takes a number 0-3.
If I rotate in the init, this is the result.
[image: Display with bottom not showing]
We can see that the "dead" pixels have moved from the top to the bottom.

Okay, so the display itself is working fine. Must be the code.

In the ST7735.h file there are these lines:

```
#define ST7735_IS_160X80 1
//#define ST7735_IS_128X128 1
//#define ST7735_IS_160X128 1
#define ST7735_WIDTH  80
#define ST7735_HEIGHT 160
```

I uncommented the IS_160_80 one since that is what I have. And I put WIDTH as 80 and HEIGHT as 160.

In the ST7735.c file there are these rows:

```
int16_t _width = 80;       
int16_t _height = 160;      
int16_t cursor_x;     
int16_t cursor_y;    
uint8_t rotation;     
uint8_t _colstart;   
uint8_t _rowstart;      
uint8_t _xstart;
uint8_t _ystart;
```

After all the STM32 inits this is all the display code I do:

```
ST7735_Init(2);
fillScreen(BLACK);
testAll();
```

I left some of them uninitialized now but I have tried with them all set to 0 too, same result.

I must be missing something, but can't figure out what. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This looks like the function which write data to the display ram is not operating properly. I mean, either pixels are not written to the first bank in the proper order or there is too many pixels written wich causes some kind of offset. Could you try to display a known gradient along the screen with to find this out?

Comment: It seems the display supports rotating the display, i.e. having it as 160x80 rather than 80x160. But you'd need the software to know that and write to the frame-buffer accordingly. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: Same issue for me, did you find the solution ? @Gripen

Comment: @simon No I did not, I tried multiple drivers and no one solved the problem. So I changed to a 1.14 inch TFT display (https://www.waveshare.com/1.14inch-lcd-module.htm) and used this driver:
https://github.com/Floyd-Fish/ST7789-STM32
Worked like a charm!

Comment: @simon Hello Simon again! See my answer to this thread! There is your solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost half a year I accidentically stumpled across a solution when I wasn't even looking for one, figure out I might as well come back to this thread and share it :)

The solution:
The display has these pins:
MOSI
SCK
RST
CS
RS

First off, in the STM32CubeIDE SPI settings, make sure that if you use jumper wires, don't have more than Baud Rate of 8 MBits/s.

Make sure Clock Polarity (CPOL) is set to Low.
Make sure Clock Phase (CPHA) is set to 1 Edge.

Before you do the ST7789_Init() function:
Make sure to set the RST, CS and RS pin.

Then have a small delay and then do the Init funciton then have a small delay and then you can go on with the display code. So in my case,
I have named the pins accordingly, this is what I do:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RST_DISPLAY_GPIO_Port, RST_DISPLAY_Pin, 1);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_DISPLAY_GPIO_Port, CS_DISPLAY_Pin, 1);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(RS_DISPLAY_GPIO_Port, RS_DISPLAY_Pin, 1);

HAL_Delay(500);

ST7789_Init();

HAL_Delay(100);
```

Summary: The problem was that the intial state of the RS, RST and CS pins were not correct, fixing this will fix the problem.
Hopefully I helped at least someone with this problem! Happy coding!

Comment: And note that RS is sometimes refered to as DC